# Jest, test suites fail because server is not closing correctly

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

I have the following setup in each of my test files:

```
const supertest = require('supertest');
const app = require('../../app.run');

let request = null;
let server = null;


beforeAll((done) => {
    server = app.listen(done);
    request = supertest.agent(server);
});

afterAll((done) => {
    sequelize.close();
    server.close(done);
});
```

My app listening method looks like this:

```
app.listen(process.env.APP_PORT, () => {
    logger.info('Server is running on port ' + process.env.APP_PORT);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Now when I run all tests with jest, the server doesn't seem to be closed correctly as I get an  EADDRINUSE error:

```
Test suite failed to run

    listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8081

      32 | app.use('/api', require('./app.routes'));
      33 |
    > 34 | app.listen(process.env.APP_PORT, () => {
         |     ^
      35 |     logger.info('Server is running on port ' + process.env.APP_PORT);
      36 | });
      37 |

      at Function.listen (node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app.run.js:34:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/e2e/auth-controller.test.js:3:13)
```

And this is an example of a test:

```
it("should register a user", async () => {
    await request
        .post('/api/users/signup')
        .send({email, password, name, surname})
        .expect(200);

    const user = await User.findOne({where: {email}});
    expect(user.active_token).toBeNull();
    expect(user.enabled).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Any idea on how to close the server correctly? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Why do you need to start the express server?

Comment: I don't need to, I would love to start the server once for all the test suites, but I didn't find a solution

Comment: Don't start it, just `request = supertest.agent(app);`

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work it still tries to call it twice

Comment: did you remove `server = app.listen(done);` line?

Comment: yeah of course, but no luck :/

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you are not properly assigning the SERVER. I'm going to assume that you are listeining from index.js so your index.js should look like below.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

//...

let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test")
    port = 4000;

const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));

module.exports = server;
```

Then in your test file your code should include the following:

```
const request = require('supertest');

let server;

describe('/your/path', () => {
    beforeEach(() => { 
        server =  require('/path/to/index.js');
    });
    afterEach(() => { 
        server.close(); 
    });

    it("should register a user", async () => {
        cont res = await request(server)
            .post('/api/users/signup')
            .send({
               email: 'myemail@mail.com',
               name: 'John Doe'
            });
        ...
        expect(res.status).toBe(200);
        ...
    });
});
```

Try not to complicate things. I would advice you have a USER MODEL instead of typing in data like you did.